# signature constraint for generic types

Tags: d

```
struct S(int a, int b) { }

void fun(T)(T t) { }
```

I want `fun` to work with `S` only.  What would the signature constraint look like?

I can't make `fun` a member of `S`, and with `void fun(T)(T t) if(is(T : S)) { }` I get `Error: struct t1.S(int a,int b) is used as a type`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`S` is not a type. It's a template for a type. `S!(5, 4)` is a type. It's quite possible that different instantiations of `S` generate *completely* different code, so the definition of `S!(5, 4)` could be *completely* different from `S!(2, 5)`. For instance, `S` could be

```
struct S(int a, int b)
{
    static if(a > 3)
        string foo;

    static if(b == 4)
        int boz = 17;
    else
        float boz = 2.1;
}
```

Note that the number and types of the member variables differ such that you can't really use an `S!(5, 4)` in place of an `S!(2, 5)`. They might as well have been structs named `U` and `V` which weren't templatized at all for all of the relation that they really have to one another.

Now, different instantiations of a particular template are generally similar with regards to their API (or they probably wouldn't have been done with the same template), but from the compiler's perspective, they have no relation with one another. So, the normal way to handle it is to use constraints purely on the API of the type and not on its name or what template it was instantiated from.

So, if you expect `S` to have the functions `foo`, `bar`, and `foozle`, and you want your `fun` to use those functions, then you'll construct a constraint that tests that the type that's given to `fun` has those functions and that they work as expected. For instance

```
void fun(T)(T t)
    if(is({ auto a = t.foo(); t.bar(a); int i = t.foozle("hello", 22);}))
{}
```

Then any type which has a function called `foo` which returns a value, a function named `bar` which may or may not return a value and which takes the result of `foo`, and a function named `foozle` which takes a `string` and an `int` and returns an `int` will compile with `fun`. So, `fun` is far more flexible than if you had insisted on it taking only instantiations of `S`. In most cases, such constraints are separated out into separate eponymous templates (e.g. `isForwardRange` or `isDynamicArray`) rather than putting raw code in an `is expression` so that they're reusable (and more user friendly), but expressions like that are what such eponymous templates use internally.

Now, if you *really* insist on constraining `fun` such that it only works with instantiations of `S`, then there are two options that I'm aware of.

**1.** Add a declaration of some kind which `S` always has and you don't expect any other type to have. For instance

```
struct S(int a, int b)
{
    enum isS = true;
}

void fun(T)(T t)
    if(is(typeof(T.isS)))
{}
```

Note that the actual value of the declaration doesn't matter (nor does its type). It's the simple fact that it exists that you're testing for.

**2.** The more elegant (but far less obvious solution) is to do this:

```
struct S(int a, int b)
{
}

void fun(T)(T t)
    if(is(T u : S!(i, j), int i, int j))
{}
```

[`is` expressions](http://dlang.org/expression.html#IsExpression) have a tendancy to border on voodoo once they get very complicated, but the version with commas is precisely what you need. The `T u` is the type that you're testing and an identifier; the `: S!(i, j)` gives the template specialization that you want `T` to be an instantiation of; and the rest is a `TemplateParameterList` declaring the symbols which are used in the stuff to the left but which haven't previously been declared - in this case, `i` and `j`.

Comment: You do not need to use a signature constraint here: `void fun(T : S!(i, j), int i, int j)(T t) {}` is more concise and doesn't introduce the dummy identifier 'u'.

Answer (score 7):

I think there are a couple of small red herrings in the other answers. You can use pattern matching to figure whether T is some instance of S, as follows.

Simplest way is to just pattern-match the argument itself:

```
void fun(int a, int b)(S!(a, b) t) {
}
```

More generally you can pattern-match in separation, inside a template constraint:

```
void fun(T)(T t) if (is(T U == S!(a, b), int a, int b)) {
}
```

In both cases you have access to the instantiation arguments.

Answer (score 3):

*"Work with `S` only"* doesn't really make sense in D, because
`S` is not a type, it's a *template*.

A template is *itself* "something" in D, unlike in other languages.

What you wrote is a **shorthand** for:

```
template S(int a, int b) { struct S { } }
```

So the *type*'s full name is `S(a, b).S`, for whatever `a` or `b` you use. There's no way to make it "generically" refer to `S`.

If you need to put a constraint like this, I suggest putting something private inside `S`, and checking that `T` has the same member.

Comment: There *is* a way to generically check for instances of `S`, see Davis' reply.

Comment: @jA_cOp: #1 of his answer is the exact same thing I put in my post (put a member and check it). But #2 is definitely something I'd never seen o.o

Comment: @Mehrdad #2 is the sort of thing that generally only people who have really studied `is` expressions know about. I only found out about it recently. Basic `is` expressions are straightforward enough, but `is` expressions can do a _lot_ (arguably too much for one construct). Also, in spite of the fact that I know the language very well, I'm increasingly reticent to say that you _can't_ do something in D. The language is flexible enough that often someone actually figures out a way to do what seems impossible (though there _are_ of course still things that _are_ impossible).

Comment: @JonathanMDavis, the `is` primary expression lets you use the template type specialization syntax outside of template parameter lists - it is not really `is` doing the work, it's D's type specialization. The fact that so few people are familiar with it is a real problem that could probably be attributed to a lack of good documentation - the template system is *really* sparsely described in the online specification, and TDPL does not elaborate.